# Cannot notifyDataSetChanged() on an opened Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, notifydatasetchanged

1. I have 5 items in my `Spinner`. I click a refresh button which fires
   an API call, which ends with a refresh on the `Spinner`.
2. I immediately tap on the Spinner to open it.
3. The API call ends while the `Spinner` is open and also calls `notifiyDataSetChanged()` on it (I can guarantee this, I checked with logs, so the data IS there).
4. Unfortunately, the Spinner does not refresh its views. So if I expect 6 items after refresh instead of 5, I still see 5.

If I repeat the test without the Spinner open, and open it after the refresh finishes, I see 6 items. So the problem is around the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Comment: No need to. Found the culprit. Thanks anyway. Question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code. just add new one and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`.

```
mSpinnerAdapter.add(object);
mSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable spinner until your refresh process ends. Or show process dialog while your API call ends. I think you cannot refresh your spinner while it is open.